# Why FINAL modifier doesn't trigger Clickhouse's merging procedure

Tags: clickhouse

There's a ReplacingMergeTree table in Clickhouse, when executing `select count(1) from tbl`, it yields 71961920. Then I executed `select count(1) from tbl FINAL` trying to trigger the merge procedure as noted in [the official document](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/from/#final-modifier):
[image]

but it turns out after running the above sql with `FINAL`, the sql without `FINAL` still yields the "wrong" result as if it was not being merged at all. Could anyone help explain? Thanks~

[image]

Comment: select does not change data on the disk, does not initiate optimize (merges).

Comment: Data is merged -- is about related data is merged during select processing in the SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

In order to force clickhouse to merge tables use `OPTIMIZE` keyword.
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/optimize/

but keep in mind this:
*Although you can run an unscheduled merge using the OPTIMIZE query, do not count on using it, because the OPTIMIZE query will read and write a large amount of data.* - [ClickHouse ReplacingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree)